# How to use print_late_styles() WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to load style into footer, below is the link for solution which is working fine for me but I want to load it using print_late_style(), anyone know how to use print_late_style()?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186065/how-to-load-css-in-the-footer

Thanks in advance.

Comment: apply_filters( 'print_late_styles', bool $print ) you can use this filter. Filters whether to print the styles queued too late for the HTML head.

Comment: You mean to say like this ?

add_filter('print_late_styles','load_any_style');

if(!function_exists('load_any_style')) {
 
 function load_any_style() {
  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' id='any-css'  href='custom.css' type='text/css' media='print' />";    
 }
 
}

Thank You :)